# How do I take 31 columns for days in pandas and group them into a single column?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a very large file that I'm trying to reformat to run QC checks.  The format is very strange how do I make it into a single column with a record for each date?

current code is:

```
group = df.groupby(['ID','MONTH'], as_index = True).sum()
```

The dataframe looks like this before any grouping:

`ID         TASK      MONTH     1       2       3     4     5         6 
 P502867    5.34545   201601                4.664981    4.6699       4.557714
 P502867    5.34545   201602    4.736791    4.664536    4.751841     4.744383`

The top numbers are the days of the month, and in the month column we have each corresponding month until 201608 (August).  Essentially I want to group this by the ID, Month, and then the have each column of the days within each month.  So this would enable me to run down the list and compare it with another file with daily records.  The output dataframe would look something like:

`ID        TASK       MONTH      DAY        VALUE
P502867    5.34545    201601       1

P502867    5.34545    201601       2

P502867    5.34545    201601       3        4.664981
P502867    5.34545    201601       4        4.6699`

Also it might even be helpful to append the month and day together? like 20160101, 20160102.  Whichever is easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `melt` the days.

```
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=df.columns[:3].tolist(), var_name='day',
              value_vars=df.columns[3:].tolist())
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.MONTH.astype(str) + df2.day.astype(str), 
                                  format='%Y%m%d')
>>> df2.sort_values(['ID', 'timestamp'])
         ID     TASK   MONTH day     value  timestamp
0   P502867  5.34545  201601   1  4.664981 2016-01-01
2   P502867  5.34545  201601   2  4.669900 2016-01-02
4   P502867  5.34545  201601   3  4.557714 2016-01-03
6   P502867  5.34545  201601   4       NaN 2016-01-04
8   P502867  5.34545  201601   5       NaN 2016-01-05
10  P502867  5.34545  201601   6       NaN 2016-01-06
1   P502867  5.34545  201602   1  4.736791 2016-02-01
3   P502867  5.34545  201602   2  4.664536 2016-02-02
5   P502867  5.34545  201602   3  4.751841 2016-02-03
7   P502867  5.34545  201602   4  4.744383 2016-02-04
9   P502867  5.34545  201602   5       NaN 2016-02-05
11  P502867  5.34545  201602   6       NaN 2016-02-06
```

Optionally, you can drop those with no values:

```
>>> df2.dropna(subset=['value'])
        ID     TASK   MONTH day     value  timestamp
0  P502867  5.34545  201601   1  4.664981 2016-01-01
1  P502867  5.34545  201602   1  4.736791 2016-02-01
2  P502867  5.34545  201601   2  4.669900 2016-01-02
3  P502867  5.34545  201602   2  4.664536 2016-02-02
4  P502867  5.34545  201601   3  4.557714 2016-01-03
5  P502867  5.34545  201602   3  4.751841 2016-02-03
7  P502867  5.34545  201602   4  4.744383 2016-02-04
```